# Prevent div content to wrap

Tags: html, css

I need to develop simple image box control with main big image and thumbnail region located at the bottom. Here is my code

```css
.frame{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

.image{
    height: 75%;
    width: 100%;
    
    background: red;
}

.thumbs{
    height: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    
    background: blue;
}

.nav{
    height: 100%;
    width: 5%;
    display: inline-block;
        
    background: green;
}

.left{
    float: left;    
}

.right{
    float: right;    
}

.thumb-images{
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    
    background: orange; 
}

.thumb{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    
    background: purple;   
}
```

```html
<div class='frame'>
    <div class='image'></div>
    <div class='thumbs'>
        <div class='nav left'></div>
        <div class='thumb-images'>
            <div class='thumb'></div>
            <div class='thumb'></div>
            <div class='thumb'></div>
            <div class='thumb'></div>
            <div class='thumb'></div>
            <div class='thumb'></div>
        </div>
        <div class='nav right'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need thumb images content region (the orange) to hide its overflow (purple rectangle represent images). I also need to have horizontal scroll. What is wrong with my markup?

Comment: I am not sure what the question you are asking is.

Comment: your images are 25% and your background is 90% (90-(25x3)=15) what do you want to do with the remaining 15%? hide it? show it to the sides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure (your question is not too clear), but I think the answer may be that you need `white-space:nowrap` on the thumb-images div.

```css
.frame{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

.image{
    height: 75%;
    width: 100%;
    
    background: red;
}

.thumbs{
    height: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    
    background: blue;
}

.nav{
    height: 100%;
    width: 5%;
    display: inline-block;
        
    background: green;
}

.left{
    float: left;    
}

.right{
    float: right;    
}

.thumb-images{
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    
    background: orange; 
    white-space:nowrap; /* this */
}

.thumb{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    
    background: purple;   
}
```

```html
<div class='frame'>
    <div class='image'></div>
    <div class='thumbs'>
        <div class='nav left'></div>
        <div class='thumb-images'>
            <div class='thumb'></div>
            <div class='thumb'></div>
            <div class='thumb'></div>
            <div class='thumb'></div>
            <div class='thumb'></div>
            <div class='thumb'></div>
        </div>
        <div class='nav right'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see you accepted my answer, but @GrumbleSnatch's was better, because mine doesn't have a horizontal scrollbar.

Answer (score 2):

Change the thumb-images class:

```
.thumb-images{
    display: inline-block;
    overflow-x: scroll; /*  causes extra horizontal content to be scrollable */
    overflow-y: hidden; /*  causes extra vertical content to be cut off */
    white-space: nowrap; /*  causes everything to stay on one line and not wrap */
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;

    background: orange; 
}
```

See it in action [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vy17oc65/)

Comment: Oh, that's what the OP wanted, with a scrollbar. Neat.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `text-align: center;` to the `.thumb-images` centers the images.

Adding `white-space: nowrap` helps keeping everything in one line.
Adding different behaviours for `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` produces the vertical scrolling, see below:

```css
.frame {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
.image {
  height: 75%;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
.thumbs {
  height: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
.nav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 5%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: green;
}
.left {
  float: left;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
.thumb-images {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 100%;
  width: 90%;
  background: orange;
  text-align: center;
  
}
.thumb {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class='frame'>
  <div class='image'></div>
  <div class='thumbs'>
    <div class='nav left'></div>
    <div class='thumb-images'>
      <div class='thumb'></div>
      <div class='thumb'></div>
      <div class='thumb'></div>
      <div class='thumb'></div>
      <div class='thumb'></div>
      <div class='thumb'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='nav right'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```